# Собрать проект с помощью gcc

Tags: gcc, c++

```
Доброго времени суток!
Скажите пожалуйста, вот у меня есть gcc. Я захотел собрать проект OpenAL, у меня есть main.c файл, папка AL с библиотеками типа "al.h" и т.д. Вопрос! я перехожу в командной строке в папочку, где main.c лежит, ввожу gcc -c main.c, на что он мне выводит: 
fatal error: AL/alut.h: No such file or directory
#include <AL/alut.h>
....................^
Ну ладно, думаю, добавлю папку AL с теми библиотеками и все норм, но нет, все-равно такая ошибка. В чем может быть проблема, кто-нибудь сталкивался?
Извините, если вдруг вопрос оказался дурацким, новичок еще в этом деле
Всем удачного вечера и спасибо заранее!
```

Comment: Если у вас есть проект, к нему полагается Makefile. Попробуйте просто запустить `make`, или даже `make && make install`.

Comment: Или (скорее даже так) ./configure сначала, а потом make. Или вопрос состоит в том, как собрать проект без помощи make?

Answer (score 2):

не нужно копировать, нужно просто указать компилятору, где искать хедеры. Делается это  с помощью опции `-I`:

```
gcc -c main.c -I/home/user/openal
```

в каталоге `/home/user/openal` должен быть каталог `AL`.

Comment: о, благодарю! а то не мог понять, прочитал статейку английскую, там было просто -I написано, я пытался - не получалось, щас попробуем. Спасибо!

Comment: Не знаю, как эта, а некоторым библиотекам ещё нужно будет к либам указывать (грубо говоря - где лежат файлы .a, .lib). Делается с помощью `-L`.

Comment: Я  правильно понял, что нужно писать путь относительно данной папки?
Допустим у меня есть папка Engine в ней есть main.c, после этого я добавляю в Engine папку lib, в которой есть папка AL с alut.h. В итоге: gcc -c main.c -I/lib - та же ошибка

Comment: путь нужно писать либо абсолютный (для начинающих это хороший вариант - сложнее ошибиться) или относительный - относительно текущего каталога, в котором происходит запуск компилятора.

И ещё - не путайте `-L` и `-l`. Это немного разные опции. Первая указывает на каталог поиска библиотеки, а вторая - на конкретное имя библиотеки.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое. Проблема пока не решается, не знаю, что это может быть. Все-равно не находит, что-то ему нужно, пока непонятно. Интересно, имеет значение то, что в #include <Al/alut.h> стоять именно угловые скобки, а не ковычки? Хотя я менял и пробовал, ошибка все-равно не изменялась. Странная ситуация :(

Comment: Почитайте о разнице между обычными и угловыми скобками. Почти в любой книге по с++.

Еще раз попробую переформулировать. В опции `-L` укажите  полный путь к каталогу, в котором находиться каталог Al. То есть, путь **не** должен выглядеть так:

    gcc .... -L/home/test/lib/Al

а так:

    gcc .... -L/home/test/lib

Comment: я уже нашел ответ, это был: gcc main.c -IC://freealut/include -IC://al/include -LC://al/lib -lOpenAL32 -LC://freealut/lib -lalut

Comment: @beraliv, на будущее, в подобных вопросах указывайте в какой ОС собираете.